# How to fill none values with a concrete timestamp in DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.1 and python 2.7.12.

Suppose the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import timestamp

data = [Row(time=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), Row (time=datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), Row(time=None) ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

How to use `df.fillna({'time': datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)})`  to fill in the `null` value/s with a specific time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try with `coalesce`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
default_time = datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
result = df.withColumn('time', coalesce(col('time'), lit(default_time)))
```

Or, if you want to keep with `fillna`, you need to pass the deafult value as a string, in the standard format:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
default_time = '1980-01-01 00:00:00'
result = df.fillna({'time': default_time})
```